# Python Camelot / Ghostscript "wrong architecture" error

Tags: python, ctypes, ghostscript, python-camelot

I have encountered an error that takes me beyond my de-bugging capabilities. Camelot's usage of Ghostscript seems to have found an executable of wrong architecture.

Steps taken:

1. `brew install Ghostscript`
2. checked to see if Ghostscript's executable could be found, [as per the docs](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html), it could not.
3. added `/opt/homebrew/bin` and `/opt/homebrew/lib` to appropriate paths (I think?)
4. as per the resolution of error #282 on Camelot's GitHub I changed `camelot/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py Line 256`

`libgs = ctypes.util.find_library("gs")`
to
`libgs = distutils.spawn.find_executable("gs")`

5. Checked dependencies again, with the new (above) code. Success. `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs`
6. `python3.9 -m pip install camelot-py`
7. Try to run Camelot with Ghostscript. Error shown below.

I should note, the `gs` in location `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs` appears to be an alias, not sure if that matters, but it stands to reason it would throw an exception. HOWEVER, the next two "finds" conveyed in the error, `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs` and `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin/gs` are both proper executables as far as I can tell.

Common sense tells me that if I were using Windows, I'd have a 64-bit vs 32-bit problem... but I am using MacOS, which I am unfamiliar with.

MacOS -- Apple Silicon M1 -- Python 3.9 -- brew installed Ghostscript -- pip installed camelot-py -- attempted via Jupiter notebook

edit -- also should note that Python 2.7 was a base install that came with the MacBook and its suggested that it not be removed. `which python` or `python -- version` returns the 2.7 version, not the 3.9 version I run.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py in <module>
    259     try:
--> 260         libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary("libgs.so")
    261     except OSError:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    451     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 452         return self._dlltype(name)
    453 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    373         if handle is None:
--> 374             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    375         else:

OSError: dlopen(libgs.so, 6): image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3a80516ee21f> in <module>
      1 file = r"/Users/joe_kiefner/Documents/Projects/Migration Station/Data_Lake/Arkansas/AR_12_10_2020.pdf"
      2 
----> 3 tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, flavor = 'lattice', pages='5')
      4 
      5 t_df = tables[0].df

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/io.py in read_pdf(filepath, pages, password, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    111         p = PDFHandler(filepath, pages=pages, password=password)
    112         kwargs = remove_extra(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
--> 113         tables = p.parse(
    114             flavor=flavor,
    115             suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/handlers.py in parse(self, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    169             parser = Lattice(**kwargs) if flavor == "lattice" else Stream(**kwargs)
    170             for p in pages:
--> 171                 t = parser.extract_tables(
    172                     p, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs=layout_kwargs
    173                 )

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py in extract_tables(self, filename, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs)
    400             return []
    401 
--> 402         self._generate_image()
    403         self._generate_table_bbox()
    404 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py in _generate_image(self)
    209 
    210     def _generate_image(self):
--> 211         from ..ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript
    212 
    213         self.imagename = "".join([self.rootname, ".png"])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/__init__.py in <module>
     22 #
     23 
---> 24 from . import _gsprint as gs
     25 
     26 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py in <module>
    274         if not libgs:
    275             raise RuntimeError("Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed")
--> 276         libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary(libgs)
    277 
    278 del __win32_finddll

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    450 
    451     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 452         return self._dlltype(name)
    453 
    454     __class_getitem__ = classmethod(_types.GenericAlias)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    372 
    373         if handle is None:
--> 374             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    375         else:
    376             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/bin/gs, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/bin/gs: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1/bin/gs: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, and managed to sort of solve it.

My problem is that I was using an x86 version of Python (through Anaconda). I discovered this by running:

```
$ file $(which python)
/Users/cscanlin/opt/anaconda3/envs/marvin/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Fixed by installing a new universal Python binary:

```
$ file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64]
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

Unfortunately no official support for arm with base Anaconda installs yet.