# `Camelot` gives error for not having the correct arm64 architecture of Ghostscript

Tags: python, arm64, python-camelot

I'm trying to use the python package `camelot` but get the following error, which I understand relates to my M1 mac I'm using:

```
>>> import camelot
>>> import pandas
>>> data = camelot.read_pdf('path/to/pdf.pdf')
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 260, in <module>
    libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary("libgs.so")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(libgs.so, 0x0006): tried: 'libgs.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibgs.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgs.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libgs.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgs.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/io.py", line 113, in read_pdf
    tables = p.parse(
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/handlers.py", line 173, in parse
    t = parser.extract_tables(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py", line 402, in extract_tables
    self._generate_image()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/parsers/lattice.py", line 211, in _generate_image
    from ..ext.ghostscript import Ghostscript
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import _gsprint as gs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/camelot/ext/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 268, in <module>
    libgs = cdll.LoadLibrary(libgs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(/Users/adrumm/lib/libgs.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/adrumm/lib/libgs.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/adrumm/lib/libgs.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/adrumm/lib/libgs.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/10.02.1/lib/libgs.10.02.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/10.02.1/lib/libgs.10.02.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/10.02.1/lib/libgs.10.02.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I think this is same issue as [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819425/python-camelot-ghostscript-wrong-architecture-error), but the sole response to that question does not help as I already have the arm64 Python installed.

Steps taken:

- `brew install ghostscript`
- Checking that Ghostscript is installed as per the [package documentation](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html) confirms that it is installed
- Same issue occurs whether in a virtual environment not

Is this even possible to fix?

Comment: If your Python is arm64, then your brew must be x86_64. Either use arm64 brew, or run Python as x86_64.

Comment: This isn't a Ghostscript question. As Siguza says above, I believe you need to make your environment consistent throughout. Either use x86_64 throughout, or use ARM throughout. It seems pretty clear that the brew Ghostscript binary is x86_64 (which is what I would expect) so you need to be running an X86_64 Python. Otherwise you'll need to build Ghostscript for an ARM target.

Comment: @Siguza that was the exact issue thank you. I made sure I had the arm64 brew available and made that the one to use. Then it installed arm64 Ghostscript and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Siguza correctly pointed to the issue being with brew. Here's how I fixed the problem if anyone else finds themselves in similar situation:

1. Ran `brew config` in to confirm I was using x86_64 brew
2. Install brew from the .pkg file found [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/latest) (I forgot to check if the arm64 brew was already installed or not though I do not think so)
3. Set arm64 brew as default: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` - [source](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3223)
4. Create a link where `camelot` looks for Ghostscript as explained [here](https://jonathansoma.com/everything/pdfs/camelot-ghostscript/)

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/lib
   ln -s "$(brew --prefix gs)/lib/libgs.dylib" ~/lib
   ```